# package android.support.v7.app does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am following the udacity course i.e. android basics:user input and stuck with an error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOle8.png)

the error i am getting is

C:\Users\hp\AndroidStudioProjects\JUSTJAVA\app\src\main\java\com\example\justjava\MainActivity.java:8: error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

please help.
course link - https://www.udacity.com/course/android-basics-user-input--ud836
lesson 1 , video 6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOle8.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vIrk.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is now called androidx.appcomapt.app.AppCompatActivity. You'll have to change the path i.e.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am also following the course and got the same error.

Use this Statement "import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;"

Instead of "import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;"

This worked for me .Hope this will help u!